# How to import my main app classes into my imported library module?

Tags: javascript, java, android, kotlin, import

So I am creating an app that has a WebView to create notes in html. To do this I use a GitHub library called Rich Text Editor (that I put in my app project folder)

Now the problem is I want to call my function from my main app folder. How do I do that? The reason I want to do this is because I'm detecting the Button onclick from the WebView that I created using "@JavascriptInterface" in one of the class. When the user clicks the button, i need to take the value in the button and use it for my other functions in the main app folder.
Can anyone  help me please?

This is my VideoViewingFragment from my main app folder

```
    fun startsomething(vidTimestamp: Float){
    youTubePlayerView.getYouTubePlayerWhenReady(object: YouTubePlayerCallback{
          override fun onYouTubePlayer(youTubePlayer: YouTubePlayer) {
                                youTubePlayer.seekTo(vidTimestamp)}})}
```

This is my WebInterface class that I made and put in the Rich Text Editor Library:

```
class WebAppInterface(var mContext: Context) {
@JavascriptInterface
fun getString(text: String) {
//get text from the button click
// call the function from VideoViewingFragment
// This is where i want to call my functions from my activity in my other main app folder
}
```

This is the JavaScript function that is called from the .js file to call the getStringFromButtonClick (in my Rich Text Editor library module). This function is called every click.Only after the user creates a button with whatever text they want to put inside it... and after it is clicked, it is called.

```
function myFunction(text){
         window.Android.showToast(text);}
```

I know this is quite a bad technique as it can cause code injection. But this is only for my own use.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following code it will help you.

```
class TestActivity : AppCompatActivity(), WebViewFragment.WebViewCallback {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test)
    
    //Make sure your webViewFragment calling from this activity 

}

override fun onButtonClick(text: String) {
    toast(text)
}
}


//This is your webview fragment
class WebViewFragment : Fragment() {
private lateinit var webViewCallback: WebViewCallback
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    if (context is WebViewCallback) this.webViewCallback = context
}

@JavascriptInterface
fun getString(text: String) {
 //get text from the button click
 this.webViewCallback.onButtonClick(text)
 // call the function from VideoViewingFragment
 // This is where i want to call my functions from my activity in my other main app folder
}


interface WebViewCallback {
    fun onButtonClick(text: String)
 }
}
```